# List DB2 backups

Tags: backup, db2

Is there a way to list the DB2 backups? All I can find is `db2 list history backup all for <dbname>` but I think you need to check through all of those to see if they've since been deleted. This seems like a simple question but I'm coming up blank.

Edit: I am using DB2 9.7 on AIX with TSM

Comment: It is always a good practice to specify which platform your question pertains to.  This may not only help get good answers more quickly, but help others search for answers for their situation.  So often people forget that there are 3 different platform groups, with different implementations.

Answer (score 5):

using this SQL you could query in an easy manner the history file

```
SELECT start_time, entry_status, operation, operationtype, backup_id,  
       devicetype, OBJECTTYPE 
  FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY 
 WHERE operation in ('B','R') 
 ORDER BY start_time DESC FETCH FIRST 30 ROWS ONLY
```

if you're using tsm you could use

```
db2adutl query db DBNAME
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is how you would query for all the backups that were taken by your database.

If you don't set `AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ = ON` for your database configuration (as well as `NUM_DB_BACKUPS` and `REC_HIS_RETENTN`) then, yes, it will show backups that were deleted from disk.

You can also use the prune command to clean out backup entries (ans their linked backup files if `AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ` is set to `ON`).

```
db2 prune history <timestamp> [with force option] and delete
```

you can also prune archived logs as well.

```
db2 prune logfile prior to <logfile name>
```